# Google calendar v3 Push notification expiry

Tags: google-calendar-api, google-oauth, google-apps-marketplace

I am using Google Calendar Push Notifications.  All is working well and I register my channel with no issue.  Changes to the calendar result in a notification as expected.

The issue is however that after an hour or so the notifications expire.

In reading the documentation I cannot work out why there is an expiry given that I am not specifying one.

When the channel is registered the response actually states an expiry date of 1 week from when I register the channel - e.g. Fri, 31 Jan 2014 03:23:59 GMT.

This is not however what I am experiencing.

Does somebody know what the prescribed behaviour is here.

Thanks for your Help

Paul

Comment: I have followed this through with Google Support and it is a known issue with Service Accounts.  Not good news but workaround is to recreate channel every 1 hour... [link]https://support.google.com/a/known-issues/15721?hl=en

Answer (score 2, accepted):

This issue is now fixed - see the following:

[Issue Details](https://code.google.com/a/google.com/p/apps-api-issues/issues/detail?id=3542)

Answer (score 1):

by default google keeps channel expiry time for one week,
How ever you can set the channel expiry time upto one month by using **ttl** variable

```
  EX: body = {
          "id": uuid,
          "type": "web_hook" ,
          "token": "something_unique",
          "address": "web hook url",
          "params": {
                     "ttl" : 864000
                     }
          }
        calendar_service = get_calendar_service(user_email)
        resource = calendar_service.events().watch(calendarId='primary', body=body).execute()
```

here **ttl** is in seconds ,and it keeps channel expiry time for 10 days

Comment: Thanks for your help Venkatesh - I have opened a ticket with Google and they asked me to set the ttl property.  They are saying the default timeout is 1 hour - which is what I am experiencing.  When I set the ttl value as in your example, it makes no difference to the timeout.  Are you experiencing something different?  After sending the watch request, the callback has the correct expiry - but it is ignored and times out after what seems to be 1 hour.

Comment: I have updated the answer,did you try the same as in above example?
with the above code able to keep channel expiry time for 10 days

Comment: Yes my json body was json = { "id" : 78, "type" : "web_hook", "address" : "https://ilinker.com/iLinkCalendar.ashx", "params" : { "ttl":864000 } }";  On watch registration it returned the correct expiry in the response - but it times out after an hour.

Comment: me too facing same problem,On watch registration it returned the correct expiry in the response but the channel is not alive upto the expiry time and didn't get the notifications from google after certain time when any actions are performed

Comment: Hi Venkatesh - I think this is a bug in the way that notifications are working/not working.  I have a ticket with Google Support but so far nothing of use to report.

Comment: HI PNC, can you please share ticket number/link so that we will also follow up regarding this issue, Thanks

Comment: Hi - the case # is 03865086

Comment: Thanks, but didn't find a ticket with this number,can you please share a link where you have raised this case

Comment: It worked quite well 15 days before, but now we too faced it. BTW, is there any option to do not set the expiry time through Watch API or by default. I would stop the notification through API rather than specify the expiry time.

Comment: good news google has fixed this bug today http://code.google.com/a/google.com/p/apps-api-issues/issues/detail?id=3542

Answer (score 1):

I too have been plagued by this apparent bug in the Calendar API.  After two days of testing I have uncovered the following:

1. This bug only seems to manifest when you watch() a calendar using a Service Account (which is always the case for Google Apps Marketplace apps).  I only tested watching a secondary calendar, so I can't confirm if the problem exists when watching a primary calendar.
2. When you include "params": { "ttl" : 172800 } you will get a channel back with an expiration header set for 2 days from now.  However, notifications will STOP being sent after 1 hour, indicating the channel is dropped, and that Google Calendar is not correctly respecting the expiration.
3. If you include "params": { "ttl" : 172800 } and watch() a calendar with a normal access token from a regular oAuth2 flow then the channel is created with the specified expiration AND notifications are sent as expected up until the expiration.  This is true whether you are watching a Gmail account's calendar OR a Google App account's calendar - as long as you use regular OAuth2 and NOT a Service Account.
4. I tried using the undocumented

-

```
body = { "expiration" : MILLISECONDS_SINCE_EPOCH, ....}.
```

instead of

```
body = { "params": { "ttl" : 172800 }, ....}.
```

This is what the Google API Python Client Library uses and it had no effect.  Channels were created with the correct expiration, but expired after an hour when using a Service Account.

This is a particularly bad bug because it appears a channel is created correctly, but it expires early and you have no way of verifying what channels are active for a particular resource.

The only workaround I've figured out so far is to renew every channel after an hour. This is NOT a long-term solution.  I will be using over 300,000 API calls per day just to keep channels active, which is a huge chunk of my quota.  If things were working correctly I would only need to renew channels at most once a week, not 24 times a day.

Comment: Yes I agree with all that you say.  I have only been using Service Accounts and have the same behaviour.  The reason that we are using Notification channels is to reduce API calls so refreshing all channels is not an option.  I'm assuming this is a bug as the purpose of notifications is to stop polling.  I'm slowly working through this issue with Google Support.

Comment: Paul - If you get any updates on your support request if you could post here as well that would be great.  I also filed a case with Enterprise Support and will report when I hear back. -Cameron

Comment: I have also filed this bug on the public issue tracker for Apps APIs.

https://code.google.com/a/google.com/p/apps-api-issues/issues/detail?id=3542

Comment: I have linked your issue to my support request - thanks for setting this up.  Currently I am being asked for log details etc so nothing to report, but I will update this thread if anything changes.

Comment: I have had a response from Google and they have acknowledged that this is now a known issue for Service Accounts.   They have added the following known issue today. https://support.google.com/a/known-issues/15721?hl=en

Comment: Thanks for the update, Paul.  It's great that they've acknowledged the issue.  Did they give you any indication that they were working to fix it? Unfortunately the "Known Issues" page seems to be the place where they post bugs that are probably not going to get fixed, at least anytime soon.

Comment: I have asked a few more questions, but no indication on a fix at this point.  Refreshing the watch as they suggest is fraught with issues not to mention generating lots of requests.  I'm going to have to stick with polling my calendars in the interim - will use this as the basis to request a higher API allotment.