# calendar push notifications is not correctly respecting the expiration

Tags: python, push-notification, google-calendar-api, google-api-python-client

Today I have registered for calendar push notification channel using watch resource and got the response to my callback url as

```
 {
'HTTP_X_GOOG_RESOURCE_STATE': 'sync',
'HTTP_X_GOOG_CHANNEL_TOKEN': 'email=venkatesh@test.mogocrm.com&domain=test.mogocrm.com',
'HTTP_X_GOOG_MESSAGE_NUMBER': '1',
'HTTP_X_GOOG_CHANNEL_EXPIRATION': 'Sat,22Feb201410: 17: 12GMT',
'HTTP_X_GOOG_RESOURCE_ID': 'zCHDID1GFplXtVdzhpwgVsMkVI4',
'HTTP_X_GOOG_RESOURCE_URI': 'https: //www.googleapis.com/calendar/v3/calendars/primary/events?alt=json&alt=json',
'HTTP_X_GOOG_CHANNEL_ID': '3c5702f8-9097-11e3-be1e-22000ab494d8'
}
```

According to Google documentation, after creating a new notification channel to watch a resource, the Google Calendar API sends a sync message to indicate that notifications are starting. The X-Goog-Resource-State HTTP header value for these messages is sync.

Even though we got a sync message, Google watch resource fails to send notifications to our server after one hour when any actions are performed in Google calendar and it seems watch resource is not correctly respecting the expiration.

We are not sure whether Google push notifications API is stable or not

Comment: See Google's bugtracker: https://code.google.com/a/google.com/p/apps-api-issues/issues/detail?id=3542

Comment: Possible duplicate:http://stackoverflow.com/q/21323950/748858